# Generate LetsEncrypt Certs to NFS share

Tags: ssl, docker, nfs, lets-encrypt, docker-compose

Im trying to generate a letsencrypt wildcard cert to use on various websites (one FQDN, multiple subdomains).  The plan is to save those certs on a NFS share I have to easily access them on various webservers.

But when I mount my NFS share to `/etc/letsencrypt` so it saves the certs to there, I get an error:

> letsencrypt    | IOError: [Errno 37] No locks available

I set the mode of the folder on the share to 777, so it should have write access.

My `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  letsencrypt:
    image: linuxserver/letsencrypt
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: host
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    environment:
    - OTHERSTUFF=blahblah
    - STAGING=true
    volumes:
    - ./config/letsencrypt:/config/dns-conf
    - Certs:/config/etc/letsencrypt

volumes:
  Certs:
    name: certs
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=10.0.1.14,rw
      device: ":/media/NAS/Certs"
```

Answer (score 2):

You may

- Use another client that doesn't try to lock the file. On the letsencrypt website, there is a large number of clients listed.
- Use your client to download the certificate to a local file system, then copy the certificate to the NFS share.
- Try using the NFS mount option `lock`, although it should be on by default, or `local_lock=all`